# AngularJS: Render specific table row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, render

So I have a simple table, where I'm using `ng-repeat` to display table rows.

And here is a behavior I want to accomplish - show one more additional raw ,that appears when I click on regular table raw, after clicked row, with only one column that holds my custom markup. Here is what I've tried

```
parentTr.after(angular.element('<tr md-row>New raw</tr>'));
```

But this just show `[[object HTMLTableRowElement]]` and the row is not being rendered. Any ideas?

P.S. Here is an image, hope this would helpful [image]

P.S. Here is how table rendered

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.status }}</td>
</tr>
```

I can't just add new row into my `rows` array, because new row has only one column, I have to extend column to the whole table length, which possible by passing `colspan` attribute to the new row

Comment: Show the logic how you are rendering the earlier rows ?

Comment: I have a $scope.rows, which I'm rendering simply with ng-repeat

Comment: So just push the new row data into the $scope.rows using the click button.

Comment: The goal is to append row exactly `after` clicked one and with `colspan=4` attribute, which is impossible through `ng-repeat`

Comment: Are you able to get your target element where you want to append the new row ?

Comment: @LuninRoman It's possible, there's an alternative directive called ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end. Just append "-start" in the ng-repeat of the first one and, when you add the second row to the template, just put ng-repeat-end. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points

Comment: @LuninRoman You'll just have to build your logic around it. You can start by placing the visibility flag on the object in the repeat, so you can control the display of each row independently.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qBirORy9AjVU0W7Gu3EW?p=preview) is the Plunker Code for the feature you want to achieve

```
$scope.appendRow = function($event){
  // I am getting target from clicked row, you can replace 
  // your target parent to append
  var targetToappend = angular.element( $event.target.parentNode.parentNode);
  targetToappend.append('<tr><td colspan="2">Target<td></tr>');
}
```

I have used a dummy HTML here and bound the click event with one of the rows just to check the functionality. As the original soruce code is not there to check that.

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
  <td ng-click="appendRow($event)"> {{ row.name }}</td>
   <td>{{ row.status }}</td>
</tr>
```

Hope this helps!